# Filtering and extracting specific dates from SQLite file using python(Anaconda)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, date

I'm trying to filter and extract a specific date with the month `2` inside my SQLite database using python and calculating their average monthly prices. This is what I've got so far...

[image]

The CurrentMonth variable currently holds the value `02`. I keep receiving invalid syntax errors. My database is here:
  [image]

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is invalid in SQLite. I think that you mean:

```
select * from stock_stats where strftime('%m', date) + 0 = ?
```

Rationale: `strftime('%m', date)` extracts the month part from the `date` column, and returns a string like `'02'`. You can just add `0` to force the conversion to a numeric value.

Note that:

- you should also filter on the year part, to avoid mixing data from different years
- a more efficient solution would be to pass 2 parameters, that define the start and end of the date range; this would avoid the need to use date functions on the `date` column.

```
date >= ? and date < ?
```